# Persist user activity in state after reload

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created an application where user can search information related to movies using react and redux. While searching user can apply some filter(For eg. time duration).  I want this filter to be active till user unselect them even after user reloads the page.

**Problem:** 
Current scenario user apply filter application will dispatch an event and store the filter information in Redux state.

But as soon as user refresh the page information about the filter get lost.

**Solution Tried:**
I have tried one solution using session storage and local storage, but I am not convinced with the solution.

It would be great if somebody can show better way of solving this problem if available.

Comment: What was the problem with the local storage solution? The filter has to be stored ***somewhere***, and that somewhere is either going to be the users browser or your server

Comment: When I used local storage filter information was still in the browser even after when I closed it. To avoid that I used session storage. One more thing I didn't find anything wrong in using session storage but I want to know if there is any better solution.

Comment: If you dont want it stored in after the browser being closed then session storage or a session cookie are your *only* solutions. Anything else would survive a browser closing

Comment: ok then I will use the session storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some simple states, like current value of filter, it would be better to use location.

For example, you have the following page: `http://example.com/users`.
Then you can preserve filter like this: `http://example.com/users?group=admin`.

The benefit of this approach is simple: you explicitly say to user the actual state of the page, he can copy that, save bookmark, or send to somebody else.

To achieve this in React code, you can do the following (I assume that you have React-router in your app):

```
class UsersPage extends React.Component {

  // should be called somewhere in onClick
  filterUserGroup(groupName) {
    this.props.router.push({
        pathname: this.props.location.pathname,
        query: {
          group: groupName
        }
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.location !== this.props.location) {
        //filter was changed, you can apply new filter value
        this.setState({
          selectedGroup: nextProps.location.query.group
        });
    }
  }

}
```